# Powershell list of objects of a class type

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I am trying to iterate through a list of objects of a class type.
The class looks like this :

```
Class UrlTestModel
{
    [String]$Name
    [String]$Url
    [String]$TestInProd
}
```

So I would like to be able to create a list of objects that contain the three strings above, then iterate through the list and do stuff with the data.
For some reason I cant see a way to do that. Seems simple enough. I am kinda new to powershell, and come from a C# background, so I might be thinking too C# and not enough powershell. :)

Comment: If you already have a list of objects it's as simple as `$list |ForEach-Object { <# Do somthing with $_ #> }` or `foreach($item in $list){ <# do something with $item here #> }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new instance this way:

```bsh
New-Object -TypeName "UrlTestModel" -Property @{
    Name = "string"
    Url = "string"
    TestInProd = "string"
}
```

Or define a constructor in your class:

```bsh
class UrlTestModel
{
    [String]$Name
    [String]$Url
    [String]$TestInProd

    UrlTestModel([string]$name, [string]$url, [string]$testInProd) {
        $this.Name = $name
        $this.Url = $url
        $this.TestInProd = $testInProd
    }
}
```

And then create a new instance like this:

```bsh
[UrlTestModel]::new("string", "string", "string")
```

You can read more about it in [about_Classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes?view=powershell-7).

Lists are basically created by using the [comma operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7#comma-operator-):

```bsh
$list = [UrlTestModel]::new("name1", "url1", "true"), [UrlTestModel]::new("name2", "url2", "false")

# or

$a = New-Object -TypeName UrlTestModel -Property @{Name = "string"; Url = "string"; TestInProd = "string" }
$b = New-Object -TypeName UrlTestModel -Property @{Name = "string"; Url = "string"; TestInProd = "string" }
$list = $a, $b
```

Iterate over a list using the [ForEach-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7) cmdlet or the [foreach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7) statement:

```bsh
$list | ForEach-Object {
    # this is the current item:
    $_
}

# or 

foreach ($item in $list) {
    # ... 
}
```

Comment: Thank you!
It didnt work while using the New-Object, but when declaring the class with a constructor, works a charm.